# Adding 1 to the looping var (in a for loop) in batch script

Tags: loops, batch-file, increment

I'm super new to batch scripts, so if there is a silly mistake here please forgive me.
I've been searching for an answer to this for a while now and have had no luck getting anything to work.

my goal:
Iterate through 10 years from 1964 to 1974 and be able to refer to "this year" and "next year" in my for loop (with the goal of moving and renaming files).
I CANNOT get "next year" to work.

```
set /a start_year=1964
set end_year=1974
set num_between=1


for /L %%A in (%start_year%,%num_between%,%end_year%) do (
    set /a current_yr=%%A
    echo %current_yr%
    set /a "next_year=%current_yr%+1"


    echo next-year=%next_year%

)

pause
```

the result (one of the chunks of the result, it repeats due to the loop):

```
filepath*\local-folder>(
set /a current_yr=1974
  echo
  set /a "next_year=+1"
  echo next-year=
)ECHO is on.
next-year=
```

Comment: Add  `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion` at the start of the script, change the %s to !s **except %%A** .add /a to `endYear` and `numBetween`

Comment: You have got to add that as an answer because it totally worked!! Thank you!!
I'd tried the delayed expansion thing before but wasn't sure where to put the !!'s and so it didnt work.

Do I need to use ! instead of % for everything else I add to the script now? (I have a section of file-copying and file-renaming that works but requires this part).

Comment: `DelayedExpansion` is only needed in a code block( i.e `(in brackets)`). So, you should be safe to use %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

Set "start_year=1964"
Set "end_year=1974"
Set "num_between=1"

For /L %%A In (%start_year%,%num_between%,%end_year%) Do (
    Set/A "current_yr=%%A", "next_year=%%A+1"
    Echo=%%current_yr%%=!current_yr!
    Echo=%%next_year%%=!next_year!
)

Timeout -1
```

The general rule is that variables which are created/modified within a code block, *(such as **`If`**/**`Else`** or **`For`**)* should be written using the exclamation marks, those which aren't can continue to use the percent characters.